# Call a nodejs script within another one

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a two files written in javascript (node.js): server.js and extra.js

In server.js. I need to call extra.js using this

node extra 123456

123456 is `process.argv[2]` of extra.js in this case

I would like to know which module should I use in order to make this call

Comment: Do you really need to run it in a separate `node` process? Why not export a function from it, and simply `require` it?

Comment: Can't you just import the functionality you need into server.js ? Or make a http call to the service that extra.js represents?

Comment: @Bergi: How to do so ?

Comment: @zerocoldTUN https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Is there a way to do that with child process (spawn) instead of exporting a function and requiring it?

Comment: @zerocoldTUN Yes, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Bergi Because the script I am calling it shall stay working forever. It's gathering data from a Bluetooth Low Energy device and writing them to JSON file in the same folder. So the main nodejs server shall call this function and let it work forever. In my case, I am not expecting a treatment with a return or a console log ending. It's about streaming to JSON file as long as data are available.

Comment: Unless you say that `server` should stop with `extra` carrying on, that's not a reason to not to use modules. The data-gathering can continue to stream even when it is loaded as a module and called. Also it makes interacting with the server much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('extra.js', ['123456']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Comment: No need to call add "node" before extra.js ? Something like this:

`const ls = spawn('node extra', ['123456']);`